# How do I normalize a filepath in C++ using std::filesystem::path?

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a path string to a normalized (neat) format where any number of directory separators `"\\"` or `"/"` is converted to one default directory separator:

```
R"(C:\\temp\\Recordings/test)" -> R"(C:\temp\Recordings\test)"
```

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

std::string normalizePath(const std::string& messyPath) {
    std::filesystem::path path(messyPath);
    std::string npath = path.make_preferred().string();
    return npath;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> messyPaths = { R"(C:\\temp\\Recordings/test)", R"(C://temp\\Recordings////test)" };
    std::string desiredPath = R"(C:\temp\Recordings\test)";
    for (auto messyPath : messyPaths) {
        std::string normalizedPath = normalizePath(messyPath);
        if (normalizedPath != desiredPath) {
            std::cout << "normalizedPath: " << normalizedPath << " != " << desiredPath << std::endl;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Press any key to continue.\n";
    int k;
    std::cin >> k;
}
```

Output on Windows VS2019 x64:

```
normalizedPath: C:\\temp\\Recordings\test != C:\temp\Recordings\test
normalizedPath: C:\\temp\\Recordings\\\\test != C:\temp\Recordings\test
```

Reading the [std::filepath](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) documentation:

```
A path can be normalized by following this algorithm:
1. If the path is empty, stop (normal form of an empty path is an empty path)
2. Replace each directory-separator (which may consist of multiple slashes) with a single path::preferred_separator.
...
```

Great, but which library function does this? I do not want to code this myself.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered by bolov:

```
std::string normalizePath(const std::string& messyPath) {
    std::filesystem::path path(messyPath);
    std::filesystem::path canonicalPath = std::filesystem::weakly_canonical(path);
    std::string npath = canonicalPath.make_preferred().string();
    return npath;
}
```

`weakly_canonical` does not throw an exception if path does not exist.
`canonical` does.

Answer (score 3):

Use `std::filesystem::lexically_normal()`. This performs a lexical operation only, and unlike `weakly_canonical` it does not query the filesystem for existing path elements, and makes no attempt to resolve symbolic links.

```
std::string normalizePath(const std::string& messyPath) {
    return messyPath.lexically_normal();
}
```